# why does git svn init xxxxx creates a new directory called Floor and initializes there and how to fix

Tags: git, azure, directory, devops, git-svn

We are moving from CloudForge SVN hosting to Azure dev ops GIT and I am moving all my repositories.    I moved 3 of them and then I get to a .net C# SFP project and its doing things differently and I don't know why.

Steps that I am following:

1. Create SFP project in devops
2. create new directory on D:\projects
3. Put authors file into directory - open in notepad++ and change to UDF8 format
4. Open GIT CMD
5. git svn init ##CloudForgeRepoAddressHEre## --no-metadata
6. git config svn.authorsfile authors.txt
7. git svn fetch
8. git svn rebase - errors but run it anyways
9. git push --set-upstream https://HorizonsQES@dev.azure.com/HorizonsQES/CSLS/_git/CSLS master

Normally in step 5 the process would initalize the empty directory in the directory I am sitting in but instead it's creating a Floor directory instead.

At this moment I'm attempting to continue onwards but I'm not sure if it's going to work properly.

Does anyone know why it's creating the floor directory?   When I do the fetch it is erroring out.

I may have to manually add this project into devops without any comments and such which for this one is not the end of the world.

[image: directoryimage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the next few lines:

> ```
> W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
> ...
> Checked through r9709
> ```

The last line says that `git svn fetch` was successful.

---

As for the `Floor` directory... That's pretty simple. You specified it yourself.

[image: edited screenshot]

See [`man git-init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) — it accepts optional `[directory]` argument in the last position, which allows you to `init` other directory than the [CWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Here it is in action:

```
[~]$ mkdir -vp /tmp/ttt
mkdir: created directory '/tmp/ttt'
[~]$ cd /tmp/ttt
[/tmp/ttt]$
[/tmp/ttt]$ ls -la #-- no output; /tmp/ttt is empty as expected from just-created new directory
[/tmp/ttt]$ 
[/tmp/ttt]$ git init foobar
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/ttt/foobar/.git/
[/tmp/ttt]$ #--                              ^^^^^^
[/tmp/ttt]$ #--                              ||||||
[/tmp/ttt]$ #-- NOTICE ----------------------//////
[/tmp/ttt]$ 
[/tmp/ttt]$ ls -a . foobar
.:
drwxr-xr-x - ulidtko 28 Sep 11:37 foobar

foobar:
drwxr-xr-x - ulidtko 28 Sep 11:37 .git

[/tmp/ttt]$ #-- I.e. in `.` (= CWD = /tmp/ttt) there's only `foobar` which is a git repo
[/tmp/ttt]$ #-- Which shows that we `git init`ed a directory other than CWD
```

`git svn init` of course forwards the call to `git init`, so that's why you have it.

If I'm guessing through your censorships correctly, you said:

```
git svn init https://..../asdf/qwer/Shop Floor Processing --no-metadata
```

You should know that per Unix Shell rules, `bash` will parse this command as `git svn init ARG1 ARG2 ARG3 ARG4` with `ARG1=https://..../asdf/qwer/Shop`, `ARG2=Floor`, `ARG3=Processing`, `ARG4=--no-metadata`. I.e. arguments are separated by whitespace. To pass anything (directory path, URL... anything) which contains whitespace *as a single argument*, you need to [quote it](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Quoting) like this:

```
git svn init "https://..../asdf/qwer/Shop Floor Processing" --no-metadata
```